# Looping XML with the lowest complexity

Tags: xml, parsing, loops, complexity-theory

I am using Java DOM parser to parse XML files. Performance is important to me and I need to write the most optimized code. I noticed that XMLs to be processed have a lot of nested tags (It can reach 5 levels in depth) and I have to retrieve information of all levels.

The dummy solution I implemented is to have nested loops each loop retrieves the node's children and passes it to the next loop.

This is a very bad practice on the level of performance and complexity as code complexity reaches O(n^5). Please, find how it can go on the code level below.

I believe divide and conquer algorithms might work in this case.

Do any of you have any suggestions to have a more optimized code to have better performance?

> for (int temp = 0; temp < contractDetails.getLength(); temp++){
>             Node detail = contractDetails.item(temp);
>             System.out.println(detail.getNodeName());
>             NodeList detail2 = detail.getChildNodes();
>
> ```
>       for (int temp2 = 0; temp < detail2.getLength(); temp2++){
>       .........
>           for (int temp3 = 0; temp < detail3.getLength(); temp3++){
>               ...............
>           }
>
>       }
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are interested in performance, don't use DOM. Other tree models in Java, such as XOM, are much faster, and easier to use as a bonus.

Secondly, your code with 5 nested loops is not O(n^5). The total number of iterations of the innermost loop is equal to the number of nodes in the document, so it's O(n) in the size of the document.

Comment: Michael, thank you very much for your input. I will try using XOM. Do you believe having such nested loops won't affect performance. Do you know of any better practice to have the same output?

Comment: Well, I would write it in XSLT or XQuery, and only consider other approaches if the performance doesn't meet requirements. Generally if performance isn't fast enough, then the cheapest way to improve it is to upgrade your hardware - a new server costs about as much as one day of a programmer's time.